# This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key "go"

Tags: ios, xcode

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFUj8.png

these are the console logs!! the error is in the first line!

this is the "go" button it talks about and the "compute" action

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oarQp.png

this is some of my code that i am using in the view controller M file.

```
- (IBAction)compute:(id)sender {
    float answer = (21.75 + [_shoeSize.text floatValue])/3;
    float feet = answer/12;
    float result = feet * [_numberOfFeet.text floatValue];

    self.answerDisplay.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", result];
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with the complete error message at the top of the stack trace in the 1st image you linked. Then do a search on the error message. You will find plenty of existing discussion on that error.

Comment: Check your .xib file, and ensure all IBActions and IBOutlets are connected properly.

Comment: Let me guess, you hooked your "go" button up to an outlet `go`, but you decided you didn't need it and deleted that from your code. But you forgot to remove it in Interface Builder too.

Comment: Gavin, thats what other people were saying, but i dont remember doing that.

Comment: i cant put more than two links so here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7PZI3.png

Comment: @Gavin is right -- this log indicates a broken connection in a xib/storyboard file.

Comment: in the storyboard file it says everything is still connected?(i go to each connection and click the dot to insure its connected to the right object)

Comment: Check that the GoButton or the ViewController in the Storyboard has not an "old" connection.

Comment: never mind guys i fixed it! i deleted go and everything it was attached to and made a new button to start fresh. it works now! thankyou everyone for the help! it was greatly appreciated.